# Recover from power outage during ntfsresize?

Tags: linux, partition, hard-drive, ntfs

After upgrading disks on our local server, I was using the "Parted Magic" boot disk along with gparted to move & resize an NTFS partition. I believe it uses the 'ntfsresize' tool internally.

However, somewhere around half way through, the power had a minor blip...and I had a heart attack.

I haven't touched or mounted the disk yet, is there any possible way to restart the operation where I left off? Failing that, what's the best way to recover my data?

Everyone always says "Oh yeah, ntfsresize is perfectly safe, as long as you don't have a power outage or something"...am I screwed?

Comment: What about your backup?

Comment: yes. yes you are screwed. have your resume ready.

Comment: haha...thanks for all the helpful comments everyone. Actually I lied...it was for a home server, with non-essential data, so I wasn't very rigorous about keeping backups. I eneded up using some random NTFS recovery tool and recovered most of the important stuff, good enough in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't resume, then give this utility a shot: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

From their website:

```
* Fix partition table, recover deleted partition
* Recover FAT32 boot sector from its backup
* Rebuild FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 boot sector
* Fix FAT tables
* Rebuild NTFS boot sector
* Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup
* Fix MFT using MFT mirror
* Locate ext2/ext3 Backup SuperBlock
* Undelete files from FAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
* Copy files from deleted FAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3 partitions.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent backup, restore from backup. That is the safest option.

If not:

First, *image the disk* (*dd* will be fine, or PartitionMagic, Norton Ghost etc.). That way, you can always try again if you mess up something while fixing. Then try some recovery tool like TestDisk.